# Phonegap + Laravel 4 How to upload file

Tags: cordova, laravel, laravel-4, phonegap-plugins

I answered this question myself so that others don't face the problems i did.

Answer (score 2):

**The Client Side(Javascript Code) :**
It took me a while to figure out how to use the file upload feature in phonegap while using laravel 4 on the server. This is for others who might be looking for some help :
 Ensure that :

- **public/images**(or any other destination folder you wish to upload fie  folder is writable or else you will get **error code : 1**
- Values of **options.fileKey** must match `Input::file(options.fileKey)->move()`
- You make a post request.

> $('.upload').on('click',function()
>               {
>
> ```
>               navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess,cameraFail,
>                 {
>                   quality: 50,
>                   destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
>                   mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
>                   sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY });
>
>         });
>
>   function cameraSuccess(imageURI)
>           {
>
>               //set file upload options
>                var options = new FileUploadOptions();
>
>                     options.fileKey="file";
>                     options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
>                     options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
>                     options.chunkedMode = false;
>
>
>                     var ft = new FileTransfer();
>
>                     ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI(url+'/file-upload'), win, fail, options);
>
>
>             function win(r) {
>                 console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
>                 console.log("Response = " + r.response);
>                 console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
>             }
>
>             function fail(error) {
>
>                 console.log("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
>                 console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
>                 console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
>             }
> ```

**The Server Side(Laravel) Code**

```
Route::post('/file-upload',function()
{
    //I am storing the image in the public/images folder 
    $destinationPath = 'images/';

    $newImageName='MyImage.jpg';

    //Rename and move the file to the destination folder 
    Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath,$newImageName);

}
```

That is all that is required on the server side. After a successful upload the success callback function **win** will run.