# Handling image file Using laravel controller

Tags: php, angularjs, mongodb, laravel-5

I need to handling my image posted by angularjs to a Laravel method.

Please can you help me:: Any Ideas!

**Note: I use Mongodb as DataBase**

Comment: you can try this - http://image.intervention.io/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload a Cordova picture to a Laravel 4 project by using an API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151858/how-to-upload-a-cordova-picture-to-a-laravel-4-project-by-using-an-api)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us [what you have tried](//whathaveyoutried.com), as well as the specific problem or error that you are encountering. Be sure to include a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).